# get the index of dynamically created row

Tags: javascript, html

I am making an web app in which I am creating rows dynamically and adding click listener to each dynamically added row. But I could not figure out how to get the rows index and to pass some variable to the listener.

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++)  {      
    var TABLE = document.getElementById('tableId');
    var BODY = TABLE.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    //making a row
    var TR = document.createElement('tr');
    TR.className = "section group";

    //creating first column
    var TD = document.createElement('td');
    TD.className = "col span_1_of_3";

    //adding click listener
    url_array[count] = result.details[count].video_url;
    TR.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(count,e);  //     ---------> 1 
    });

    count++;
}
```

In line indicated `---> 1`, I have a global variable count initialized to zero and its value is last row index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. When the `click` handler fires, then `count` is set to the last one. Try wraping your `.addEventListener` method with an anonymous function:

```
(function(count){
    TR.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        console.log(count,e);  //     ---------> 1 
    });
})(count);
```

This will work, because functions create seperate scope unlike `for` loop.

Comment: its working ......could you explain it more with any link.....as i am a newbie....

Comment: @shark Have a look at this: http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62  (it's almost the same case as yours). Also try googling "closure" and "scoping" with "javascript".

Comment: One more thing I am not able to pass any other variable other then count.... how could i acheive this any way round this